# Is there any way to make enum display spaces and images?

Tags: c#, enums, grouping

I am using enum for my group description in listview and I am trying to make it display some more user friendly text but I getting an error which says cannot implicitly convert type string to Mærke

Enum

```
public enum Mærke { 
 Alfa_Romeo,
 Audi,
 Aston_Martin__________________________________________________________5x114,
BMW,
 Chervolet,
Chrysler,
Citroën,
Daewoo,
Daihatsu,
Dodge,
Ferrari };
public Mærke mærke { get; set; }
```

Class

```
public class biler
{
    public string billed { get; set; }

    public string Model { get; set; }

    public string Type { get; set; }

    public string Årgang { get; set; }

    public string Krydsmål { get; set; }

    public double ET { get; set; }

    public double centerhul { get; set; }

    public string bolter { get; set; }

    public string hjul { get; set; }
     
    public Mærke mærke { get; set; }

}
```

List

```
  items.Add(new biler() { billed = "img/Biler/aston martin.png", Model = "DB9", Årgang = "03-", Krydsmål = "5x114.3", ET = 62.5, centerhul = 68.1, bolter = "M14x2", mærke = Mærke.Aston_Martin__________________________________________________________________________________________________5x114 });
 CollectionView view = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView (hjuldata.ItemsSource);
PropertyGroupDescription groupDescription = new PropertyGroupDescription("mærke");           
view.GroupDescriptions.Add(groupDescription);
```

[image: how do I get a icon over here?]

Comment: To be honest: I don't understand the problem and what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: All other things aside, `Aston_Martin__________________________________________________________________________________________________5x114` does not seem to be a very good name... especially since that is the only Aston Martin in the enum. I would just call it `Aston_Martin` or if you need to differentiate between two different Aston Martin makes then `Aston_Martin_5x14`

Comment: is mostly becuase there is diffrent bolt circle for diffrent cars witch i want to show in the group description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should do it if that is what you are looking for and as for the picture i dont think headers supports that

```
using System.Reflection;
public static class EnumExtensions
{

    public static string DisplayName(this Enum value)
    {
        FieldInfo field = value.GetType().GetField(value.ToString());

        EnumDisplayNameAttribute attribute
                = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(field, typeof(EnumDisplayNameAttribute))
                    as EnumDisplayNameAttribute;

        return attribute == null ? value.ToString() : attribute.DisplayName;
    }
}

public class EnumDisplayNameAttribute : Attribute
{
    private string _displayName;
    public string DisplayName
    {
        get { return _displayName; }
        set { _displayName = value; }
    }
}

public enum Mærke 
{
    [EnumDisplayName(DisplayName = "Alfa Romeo 5x114")]
    Alfa_Romeo,

public string mærke { get; set; }
mærke = Mærke.Alfa_Romeo.DisplayName()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var mærke = Merke.Alfa_Romeo; // example
var withSpaces = mærke.ToString().Replace("_", " ");
```

This should solve it for you. There's nothing built-in to do that so you COULD write an extension method like such:

```
public static string WithSpaces(this enum theEnum){
  return theEnum.ToString().Replace("_", " ");
}
```

and then just use that in your code:

```
var mærke = Mærke.Alfa_Romeo.WithSpaces();
```

Comment: i be getting an error 

'Mærke' does not contain a definition for 'withspaces' and no extension method 'withspaces' accepting a first argument of type 'Mærke' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Yes, of course, it does not exist, you have to write it as an extension method, for example like I showed you :)

Comment: i have updatet my question i am not sure where to place it since i getting the errors when i place it under the enum 
in the class
and using Mærke.Alfa_Romeo.WithSpaces in the items list